# Which fruits and vegetables can feature russeting?

Tags: vegetables, fruits

Which other fruits and vegetables than apples, pears and potatoes can feature [russeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russeting)?

For example this nectarine: that stain is a scab or is a russet? To me it looks like mild scab but maybe the nectarines can also feature russeting?

[image: This nectarine]

I'll provide here the image of a russet pear for reference:

[image: Russet pear]

Later edit: Here's a very interesting nectarine - scabs or russeting?

[image: Stained nectarine]

Comment: You might want to add the plant-recommendations tag to this question, and edit it to conform with the rules for that tag. Although I personally think this sort of question should be allowed as on-topic as is, I'm not sure that it's mentioned in the help center, and might be better for the Biology StackExchange site.

Comment: @Shule - Thanks, where can I find the rules for the plant-recommendations tag?

Comment: If you edit your question and start to type the tag name in the tags input box, it'll show the tags that match what you've typed so far, with a description of each tag. The plant-recommendations tag says its rules in the description it gives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peaches, apricot, quince, medlar, etc. But other damage to fruits, like plums, tomatoes and grapes could make a strong and brown (russeting like) new peel on damaged parts.

In your case, I think it is the second reason, just damaged peel, which caused a new harder tissue to be generated. A dry period followed by a lot of water (rain or irrigation) is one common cause.

Comment: corrected spelling - for interest's sake 'peal' is the sound made by bells (for instance) and 'peel' (noun, can also be a verb as in 'remove the peel of the fruit') is the rind or skin of a fruit...

Comment: @Bamboo in that example, peel was used as a noun again, not a verb.. xD remove was the verb.

Comment: @J.Musser Yea, you're right - I should have said 'peel the fruit' meaning to remove the peel, when used as a verb...sorry Giacomo, hope its clear now!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's considered russeting, but fruits with a similar-looking skin include such as the Farmer's Jalapeno, the Idaho Potato cucumber, the Sikkim cucumber, the Gagon cucumber, and netted muskmelons. You might also check out sweet potatoes, salsify, sunchokes, ginger and other stuff, which appear to be russeted.

I think we need a better definition than Wikipedia currently has to clearly know what is and isn't russeted. For all we know, scabs might be encompassed by that definition, too. I've seen similar things on apricots and Stanley plums as I see on the nectarine you pictured.

I've seen other, similar things on tomatoes and apricots that I'm pretty sure were just what alternaria lesions look like in a dry and semi-arid climate (although the fruit isn't hurt). They usually look like round (not always round), small scabs instead of thicker strips of potato-like skin, though.

Also, they're not vegetables, or even plants, but some mushrooms appear to be russeted (especially some brown kinds).

Comment: Very good and informative answer. I accepted the other answer but this one is equally good. Thanks